# Cronjob to generate and store XML file

Tags: php, xml, caching, cron

please can anyone help me to create a php file (to be ran via cronjob) that generates a xml file on my server accessing a specific URL and download the xml file from the url and cache a copy of this once per day in a particular directory on my server? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will download the remote file at mid-night.

```
0 0 * * * curl -L http://remote.server.org/file.xml -o /opt/xml/file.xml
```

Comment: thank you, really, but this is not working on my server, I didnt know that dreamost requires a cronjob written inside a php file, so i need this in php, can you make it in php?

Comment: @LorenzoFedericoPascucci Apologies, no. When you completely change a question you should also consider retagging it.